# Gracefully Reload flask app systemd service

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, systemd

I'm using nginx and gunicorn to serve the Flask app. The problem is when I make any change in APIs and to have those changes into effect I'm doing

```
sudo service nginx reload && sudo systemctl restart myapp
```

But sometimes it gives 502 errors. My assumption is that there are already ongoing API requests served by the server while I'm doing `systemctl restart myapp`.

What is the best way to reload the service without any downtime and also the existing API calls shouldn't be affected as well?

Comment: Gunicorn supports graceful restarting via SIGHUB signal it seems. More information here: https://nts.strzibny.name/gunicorn-graceful-restarts/#:~:text=Gunicorn%20supports%20graceful%20restarts%20with,the%20new%20version%20of%20it.

Comment: @ThePjot, Thanks for the answer but the HUP signal closes the existing request and throws 502 error.